# Which Classes are required for JDBC Driver Development Documentation (SPI)

Tags: java, jdbc, provider, extensible, service-provider

If I wanted to implement a JDBC Driver, how would I know which interfaces/abstract classes I would need to implement in order to play successfully? In reading through the source, it looks like there are classes that I would consider both API(e.g. DriverManager) and SPI in the java.sql package.

I've been reading through the documentation but I am yet to find "In order to develop a driver you need to implement Driver, Connection, ResultSet, etc."

FYI - The reason I ask is that I am developing an API that includes a Provider. I'm trying to determine the best way to structure and document my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should consult a JDBC specification for understanding what's required to build a JDBC driver. Below is link to JDBC 3 specs from JCP community
http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=54

Comment: There is a JDBC 4.1 Specification [(here)](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jdbc-4_1-mrel-spec/jdbc4.1-fr-spec.pdf). Section 6, specifically 6.3.  Thanks!